# Higher accuracy of numerical derivative in 2D case

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Recently, I face a problem about solving a PDE (2D in spatial direction) and I stuck on the discretization of the 1st order derivative. My stencil is as follow
[image: Stencil]
There are five points in my stencil. And my problem is to use the five points to derive the 2nd order accurate numerical derivatives of $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ at $(x_{i},y_{j+1/2})$ and $(x_{i},y_{j-1/2})$ and also $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}$ at $(x_{i+1/2},y_j)$ and $(x_{i-1/2},y_j)$. Say, the two partial derivative at the mid-point of the mesh grid. (In fact, they are not mid-point in my work. But for the sake of simplicity, we assume they are mid-points.)

**My try:**

I want to make a quadratic polynomial to approximate the derivative I need. But, the complete quadratic polynomial is generated by $1$, $x$, $y$, $xy$, $x^2$ and $y^2$. That is, there are 6 coefficients need to determined. But I only have 5 points in my stencil.

Additionally, I would like to use an incomplete interpolation. For example, to approximate $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}$ at $(x_{i+1/2},y_j)$, I can use $u_{i,j+1}$, $u_{i,j}$, $u_{i,j-1}$ and $u_{i+1,j}$ to make an incomplete quadratic polynomial generated by $1$, $x$, $y$ and $xy$. But, when I calculate the coefficient matrix:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x_iy_{j+1}& x_i& y_{j+1}& 1\\
x_iy_j& x_i& y_j& 1\\
x_iy_{j-1}& x_i& y_{j-1}& 1\\
x_{i+1}y_j& x_{i+1}& y_j& 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
I found that it is singular. 
If I use $u_{i-1,j}$ replace $u_{i,j}$, the matrix is also singular.

Then, I stuck. Are there some tricks to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can't actually determine the coefficient for $xy$ term, since all Taylor expansion of $u_{i,j}$ are essentially expansions by $x$ or $y$, without any mixed derivative term. Moreover, that term *is not needed* for the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$, since its derivatives simply vanish on the stencil axes.

The second order accurate approximation for $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ can be obtained just from 1D formulas. And that completely agrees with the definition of the partial derivative. That's a derivative with respect to one variable while the others are held constant.